# appendChild method in a simple carousel with pure JavaScript

Tags: javascript, carousel

I am trying to make a simple JavaScript carousel from scratch.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uubfwdm5/)

**CSS**

```
#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    width: 450px;
    height: 150px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#container{
    position: absolute;
    width: 450px;
    height: 150px;
}
.child{
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 60px;
}
#a{ background: #FF0000; }
#b{ background: #FFFF00; }
#c{ background: #00FFFF; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="a" class="child">a</div>
        <div id="b" class="child">b</div>
        <div id="c" class="child">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
var firstval = 0;
function Carousel(){
    firstval += 2;
    parent = document.getElementById( 'container' );
    parent.style.left = "-" + firstval + "px";
    if( !( firstval % 150 ) ){
        setTimeout(Carousel, 3000);
        firstval = 0;
        var firstChild = parent.firstChild;
        parent.removeChild( firstChild );
        parent.appendChild( firstChild );
        return;
    }
    runCarousel = setTimeout(Carousel, 20);
}
Carousel();
```

Till now, it cycles like this:

```
a b c
b c -
c a -
a b -
```

I think there is something wrong with the append and timing.

## Question

What am I doing wrong? Should I use `appendChild` and `removeChild` method in another way?

Comment: Why don't you wanna use libraries?

Comment: Because I want to learn coding javascript and this is a training thing, not production

Comment: When you debug it, where does it go wrong?  Where does the logic deviate from what you expect?

Comment: Ah, that's fine, @Arash... All the best.

Comment: Please take a look at the fiddle. it should remove firstChild and append it to last position (like circulation) after every transition (150px movment). but it does not

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this line:

```
var firstChild = parent.firstChild;
```

… to this:

```
var firstChild = parent.firstElementChild;
```

Otherwise, you'll sometimes be grabbing the whitespace text nodes.

You don't need the following code, because `appendChild` will automatically move `firstChild`:

```
parent.removeChild( firstChild );
```

Finally, reset the container's left to 0 here:

```
parent.appendChild(firstChild);
parent.style.left= 0;
```

Otherwise, the `-150px` offset will cause the second child to disappear offscreen when the first is appended to the parent.

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wzkLjh8s/)

Answer (score 0):

I have created a carousel in the past that matches your criteria, you can find it here https://github.com/luckyape/lucky-carousel/blob/master/lucky-carousel.js

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! but I want to do it with pure javascript, not jQuery