# How do i make this pure JS carousel show the first image?

Tags: javascript

I have this pure JavaScript carousel that i have found from another question asked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563747/simple-carousel-with-pure-javascript) (Im not taking ownership of this code).

I need to make the carousel show the first image, it is showing the second image currently, (My knowledge of JavaScript isn't that great, so i have tried all that i can).

(This is just for a project at collage.)

```js
var firstval = 0;

function Carousel() {
    firstval += 2;
    parent = document.getElementById('container');
    parent.style.left = "-" + firstval + "%";
    if (!(firstval % 100)) {
        setTimeout(Carousel, 3000);
        firstval = 0;
        var firstChild = parent.firstElementChild;
        parent.appendChild(firstChild);
        parent.style.left= 0;
        return;
    }
    runCarousel = setTimeout(Carousel, 20);
}
Carousel();
```

```css
#wrapper {
            position: relative;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            margin: 0 auto;
            overflow: hidden;
        }
        #container {
            position: absolute;
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
        }
        .child {
            width: 100%;
            height: 300px;
            padding-top: 35px;
            float: left;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 60px;
        }
        #a {
            background: #FF0000;
        }
        #b {
            background: #FFFF00;
        }
        #c {
            background: #00FFFF;
        }
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="container">
        <div id="a" class="child">a</div>
        <div id="b" class="child">b</div>
        <div id="c" class="child">c</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wzkLjh8s/5/)

Answer (score 0):

### Here is a very simple solution

Just add a timeout to your initial call of Carousel():

```
setTimeout(function(){
    Carousel();
}, 3000);
```

Working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wzkLjh8s/6/